# Item escolhido no Spinner , ser uma variavel global

Tags: java, android, variáveis

Boa tarde pessoal ,

Eu tenho uma activity que possui um Spinner , o valor escolhido nesse Spinner é enviado para uma outra activity em que nela faço o getIntent e recebo o valor do Spinner , minha duvida é , gostaria de transformar o Item recebido em uma variavel global , para utilizar ela em qualquer Activity .

Segue o codigo de minhas Activitys.

Activity que envia os dados :

"SecondActivity"

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    //referencia a Spinner
    //Spinner coligada;

    //final TextView nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvNome);
    //final TextView sobrenome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvSobrenome);
    //final Spinner pday = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    final Spinner spcoligada = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.coligada);








    //spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter adaptercoligada= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.coligada, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spcoligada.setAdapter(adaptercoligada);



    Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);







    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //chamada para a nova Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, TerceiraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("coligada", spcoligada.getSelectedItem().toString());


            //intent.putExtra("nomePessoa", nome.getText().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("sobrenomePessoa", sobrenome.getText().toString());
            //intent.putExtra("day", pday.getSelectedItem().toString());










            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}




@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
    }
```

E esta é a "TerceiraActivity" que recebe os dados.

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TerceiraActivity extends Activity {








@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terceira);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String parametro = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("nomePessoa");
    //String psobrenome = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("sobrenomePessoa");
    //String ppday = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("day");

    String pcoligada = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("coligada");











    //TextView nome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvNome);
    //TextView sobrenome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txvSobrenome);
    TextView coligadas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spvcoligada);







    //nome.setText("Olá " + parametro + ", Tem de fazer a barba " );
    coligadas.setText("coliga escolhida : "+ pcoligada);


}


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cria uma variábel global com o mesmo nome da que recebe e, na hora de receber, usa o this.variável... assim ela se torna global...não sei se vai ajudar.
ex: declara uma variavel int i como global na terceira activity e na hora de receber esse valor da segunda, usa por exemplo this.i = i; (o primeiro i é da terceira activity e o segundo i é o que você recebeu da segunda)

Comment: Opa , segui essa mesma linha de pensamento sua , criei uma classe global com as variáveis que quero que sejam globais. Então defini o valor na segunda activity " Global.class.vlor = spcoligada. E está dando certo , obrigado amigo

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugiro-lhe duas hipóteses:

1ª Criar uma classe de variaveis `static`, assim basta chamar o nome da classe.variavel, ex:

```
public class Globais{
    static String coligada;
}
```

2ª Guardar na memória do telemovel, caso queira guardar essa variavel mesmo após fechar a aplicação, neste caso depende agora do que pretende fazer na sua aplicação.
Para tal usamos a classe `SharedPreferences`, ex:

Inicializar

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Receber

```
String storedPreference = preferences.getString("coligada", "valorPorDefeito");
```

Guardar

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("coligada", pcoligada); // varivel a guardar
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Pode ser utilizando a classe global. O código acima do global em qual Activity coloco ele ?

Comment: Não coloca em nenhuma Activity, deve criar uma nova classe com um nome qualquer e la dentro define as suas variaveis, depois para utilizar as variaveis na Activity apenas escreva o nome da classe que criou com um ponto e o nome da variavel (static), ex: MinhaClasse.variavel = "teste";

Comment: Certo , outra coisa , dentro dessa classe que irei criar e definir as variaveis , como faço para que essas variaveis venham de um Spinner ?